# Django Rest Framework - Loading fixtures in an APITestCase?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using [django-rest-framework](http://www.djangorestframework.com) to create an API. I'm using the framework's [`APITestCase`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing#test-cases) to test some of my endpoints.

The documentation doesn't specify a way to load fixtures and the traditional `fixtures= ['initial_data.json']` doesn't seem to be working.

How would one go about loading fixtures?

Comment: do you want to know how load fixture in django ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way you describe should work also. Make sure you're declaring the fixtures in the test class. An example below:

```
class MyViewsTestCase(APITestCase):

    fixtures = ['some_testdata.json']

    def test_random_thingy(self):
        variable = 'hello'
        self.assertEqual(variable, 'hello')
```

Every time you're test is run, the fixtures will be loaded in and removed after the test has run.

Comment: Thanks @timop. My mistake was placing the line `fixtures = [...]` inside my `setup` function.

Answer (score 3):

Fixtures don't really have anything to do with the fact that you are testing the app. All you need is a *fixtures* folder inside your app folder, which must contain a file called *initial_data.json*. When you run migrate or syncdb, the fixtures are automatically inserted into your db.

Here is how it should look:

```
your_app
  |
  |__ models.py
  |__ views.py
  |__ fixtures
         |
         |__ initial_data.json
```

You don't need to include/write any other things.